# Iterating a Linkedhashmap

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have a `LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`.

By default, all of the values are populated with a `" "` and there are three keys

I want to check if any of the values for any of the three keys is not equal to a `" "`.

This is what I have done so far ` 
   boolean checkMapContent(LinkedHashMap> Map) {

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : Map.entrySet())
     {
        String key = entry.getKey();

        ArrayList<String> labelValue = entry.getValue();
        for (String entry1 : labelValue)
        {
            if (!entry1.equals(" ")) 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
     }
    return true;
}`
```

Comment: is there only three keys or keys may differ in numbers?

Comment: there are only three keys currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public boolean hasNotEmpty(LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> map) {
        for (ArrayList<String> list: map.values()) {
            for (String str: list)
                if (!str.equals(" "))
                    return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This returns true if he has a list that has " ", "something" and false if he has a list that has "something", "something".  I'm fairly sure that's not what OP is asking.

Comment: Ok, it isn't *wrong* per se, so I'll remove downvote.

Answer (score -2):

```
for(LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> l1:mapName.entrySet())
{
   ArrayList<String> a1=l1.getValue();

  if(!a1.contains(" "))
    //do something 

 }
```

Comment: This won't even compile.  The key isn't an `ArrayList`, it is a `String`, and the `//do something` should be part of your answer.

Comment: @Neil my bad and do something is there because the user didn't specify what he wants to do once a match occurs.

Comment: I'm guessing that he means to return true or false according to whether or not it contains a non-space value.  What he does with that boolean is entirely up to th OP.  It doesn't have to be in the same place.  :P